# Why is the output like this? I do not understand how the indexing is working

Tags: numpy, artificial-intelligence, data-science

How is it indexing it? Why is the output [1,4,5]?

I am following the tutorial on http://cs231n.github.io/python-numpy-tutorial/#numpy

```py
a = np.array([[1,2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])

# An example of integer array indexing.
# The returned array will have shape (3,) and
print(a[[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 0]])  # Prints "[1 4 5]"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called fancy indexing in numpy.

You can image the first list and the second list as x-axis and y-axis. So `a[[0,1,2],[0,1,0]]` is like getting three elements which their coordinates are `(0,0), (1,1), (2,0)` from `a`.

```py
a[0,0] # 1
a[1,1] # 4
a[2,0] # 5
```